# Which 3rd party Code-by-Contract library is most like MS's .NET 4.0 library?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts, design-by-contract, contract

I want to jump into coding by contract.  I got VS2010 (with the C# 4.0 compiler) but I have to target the 3.5 framework.

What 3rd party code by contract library has classes and interface the most like the .NET 4.0 ones?

Comment: Have you tried just using [Microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)? It works by rewriting the MSIL, so it's not really a "library", and I expect it would work just fine on 3.5.

Comment: When I add "using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;" It says, Contracts isn't there.  MSDN says it is in mscorlib.dll.  I'd be surprised if I can reference the 4.0 version of that from a project targeting 3.5.

Comment: Try referencing the Microsoft.Contracts dll. That's where the 3.5 classes used to be, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [user guide](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf):

> Starting with the CLR v4, the Contract
>   class and related types reside in
>   mscorlib.dll. Prior to CLR v4, these
>   types appear in a separate assembly
>   called Microsoft .Contracts. dll that
>   is installed under
>   %PROGRAMFILES%/Microsoft/Contracts/PublicAssemblies.
>   You can need to add a reference to
>   this assembly if you are compiling
>   against a pre 4.0 CLR.

You may have some interesting issues if you want to use the same built assembly against both 3.5 *and* 4.0 (I don't know - it may just work) but if you're just using 3.5, that should be okay.

The extension installs into VS2008 as well as VS2010, I believe.

Comment: You can build the same assembly against multiple CLR versions?  Actually... why would you want to?

Comment: @R. Bemrose: If you have some applications running against .NET 3.5 and some against .NET 4.0, you may well only want to build once... if it works.

Comment: I believe the relevant classes are compiled into *your* assembly by the CC rewriter, so that there shouldn't be any versioning problems. (At least this is what I've gathered from Reflector!)

Comment: @Porges: That's definitely the case for a lot of the stuff, but I wasn't sure whether it was *all* classes...